# How to add a class to a clicked <li> and remove this class from its siblings using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some `<li>` elements inside `<ul>` element in the navigation bar , There is a class called "active" that has some properties to define the active page , I want to add this class to one of them when it is clicked and remove it from this `<li>` siblings using Javascript without any frameworks just pure Javascript .

```
<ul class='tabs'>
   <li class='active'>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

So when another page name is clicked the 'active' class is removed from the others and added to that page name.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li'), function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
         var activeItem =  document.querySelector(".tabs li.active");
       if(activeItem)
       {
         activeItem.classList.remove("active");
       }
       el.classList.add("active");
    });
});
```

code edited in case you don't have any initial active items

Answer (score 1):

A list of link nodes can be selected using `document.querySelector` and an event listener attached for click events.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li');

function activate(links) {
  links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.classList.remove('active');
  });
  this.classList.add("active");
}

links.forEach(function(link) {
   link.addEventListener('click', activate.bind(link, links));
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class='tabs'>
   <li class='active'>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the most efficient way to do it using only 1 event listener on the parent `UL`:

```js
document.querySelector('.tabs').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var current = e.target; // the item clicked

    // all li items
    var items = current.parentElement.querySelectorAll('li');
    
    // go through each li and remove .active unless current
    Array.prototype.slice.call(items).forEach(function (item) {
        item.className = (item === current) ? 'active' : '';
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class='tabs'>
   <li class='active'>Home</li>
   <li>About</li>
   <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```